# Using value of state to reference another state. (for eg, { this.state.[StateRefHere] } )

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Basically, I am doing some conditional rendering. I have two sets of state currently. Selected, which is what product is selected, and doors, which is an array of the door products.

I am trying to map out whatever product is selected. So to map out doors for example, I need to do

```
this.state.doors.map
```

However, the word 'doors' in the map needs to be based on whatever the 'selected' state is. If the 'selected' state was 'windows' for example, it would read

```
this.state.windows.map
```

So, the part

```
this.state.[dynamic].map
```

needs to be referenced based on the 'selected' state.

I tried

```
this.state.{this.state.selected}.map
```

but that just throws out a bunch of errors.

Is there something I am missing here?

Answer (score 1):

You have to do:

```
this.state[this.state.selected].map
```

This is known as [Square brackets property access](https://dmitripavlutin.com/access-object-properties-javascript/): object['property']`